# Requests download a file which has a javascript on-click download?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I want to download a file from the following url:

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions"

# Download(.csv) is the element I have to click.

# the following code doesn't work.
header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=20, headers=header)
    with open("/home/pms/corp_action", 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

```
# The element on inspection

<a id="CFcorpactionsEquity-download" data-url="" href="javascript:downloadCSV('CFcorpactionsEquity-download')"><img src="/assets/images/icon-xls.svg" alt=""> Download (.csv)</a>
```

I am trying to figure out how to download the file using requests and I am very interested to learn the process to identify the correct `params` or other things required to make this happen.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work". Are you getting an error, does nothing happen, does the file have the wrong output?

Comment: @mousetail I get a file which has `head` and `body` basically says: Resource not found.

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding "TIA" and other chatty material to your posts.

Comment: I sometimes offer the following advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be what you think it is. Usually when you use `href` in `a` tag it'a a URL link like the one you provided.
I this case it's a call Java Script function called downloadCSV. You can find this function in here: [corporate-filings.js](https://www.nseindia.com/dist/js/sections/corporate-filings.js) - it starts at linbe 4710:

```
function downloadCSV(id) {
  try {
    var csvUrl = void 0;
    if ($("#" + id).data("url") !== "") {
      csvUrl = $("#" + id).data("url") + "&csv=true";
    } else {
      csvUrl = "/api/" + activeApiName + (activeApiName.includes("?") ? "&" : "?") + "index=" + innerActiveTab + "&csv=true";
    }
    window.open(csvUrl, "_blank");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("downloadCSV", e.message);
  }
}
```

It uses external variables like `activeApiName` to stick together the URL to which it redirects user on a new page using `window.open(csvUrl, "_blank");`

Buut there's also an easier way to evaluate where the file comes from. I just dovnloaded it and checked the URL it came from. It's `https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-corporateActions?index=equities&csv=true`. For the implementation in python I suggest you basically copy-paste [this solution](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-download-a-csv-file-from-a-url-in-python) and replace the URL. The only problem might be that the website owners may change how the downloadCSV function works or the value of `activeApiName` and you will have to **scrape** it raw again.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I tried the solution on the link, I still get the same file i.e. the file which has `Resource not found`. Used the `api` url.  What is the easier way to evaluate where the file comes from?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap.